# How can I share screen as a webcam?

Tags: screen, webcam, sharing

Anyone know of a easy way to make my screen become my webcam? That OBS plugin didn't work for my and I need a solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: The OBS way should work... mind sharing what exactly you did, and we can probably troubleshoot that?

Comment: I'll do it later - I need to install it again